# prevent firefox from displaying "To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action ..."

Tags: firefox

Whenenver I reload a page that submits data via POST, I get this message.

However, for some pages (particularly games) I do not mind re-sending a POST request. The action is of little consequence, and I want it to be as fast as possible.

Can I, as a USER, not a website developer, turn off this warning for a specific page?

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871705/to-display-this-page-firefox-must-send-information-that-will-repeat-any-action

Answer (score 0):

You cannot turn off this warning. There is no mechanism for doing that,
because this is a pretty serious warning about an action that might have
serious consequences.

This happens when you have accepted a form and wish to go Back to that form.
However, doing that may possibly not display an empty form, but, depending on
the browser, *may execute again accepting the form*.

If you have just bought your new washing machine and went back to the
payment form, you might be surprised to later see that your bank account
was debited twice for this one machine ...

The web developer that created the form did not think about this possibility
and has not taken steps to avoid it using
[Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
You, the user, should be absolutely sure when going back that you don't
mind if the form gets executed again, or must know from experience that
your browser will not re-submit this one form.